# Renaming file extension using pathlib (python 3)

Tags: python, windows, pathlib

I am using windows 10 and winpython. I have a file with a .dwt extension (it is a text file). I want to change the extension of this file to .txt.

My code does not throw any errors, but it does not change the extension.

```
from pathlib import Path

filename = Path("E:\\seaborn_plot\\x.dwt")

print(filename)

filename_replace_ext = filename.with_suffix('.txt')

print(filename_replace_ext)
```

Expected results are printed out (as shown below) in winpython's ipython window output:

E:\seaborn_plot\x.dwt

E:\seaborn_plot\x.txt

But when I look for a file with a renamed extension, the extension has not been changed, only the original file exists. I suspect windows file permissions.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You have to actually rename the file not just print out the new name.

1. Use [Path.rename()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rename)

   ```
    from pathlib import Path
    my_file = Path("E:\\seaborn_plot\\x.dwt")
    my_file.rename(my_file.with_suffix('.txt'))
   ```

Note: To replace the target if it exists use [Path.replace()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.replace)

2. Use [os.rename()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename)

   ```
    import os
    my_file = 'E:\\seaborn_plot\\x.dwt'
    new_ext = '.txt'
    # Gets my_file minus the extension
    name_without_ext = os.path.splitext(my_file)[0]
    os.rename(my_file, name_without_ext + new_ext)
   ```

Ref:

1. [os.path.splitext(path)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext)
2. [PurePath.with_suffix(suffix)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.with_suffix)

Comment: `Path` has `rename` and `replace` methods, e.g. `filename.replace(filename.with_suffix('.txt'))`. For Unix-like behavior we want `replace`. In Windows, `os.rename` or `Path.rename` raises `FileExistsError` if the target exists. In Unix, `rename` will silently replace an existing target.

Answer (score 11):

From the docs:

> ## `Path.rename(target)`
>
> Rename this file or directory to the given *target*. On Unix, if *target* exists and is a file, it will be replaced silently if the user has permission. *target* can be either a string or another path object.
>
> <sup>[`pathlib` — Object-oriented filesystem paths on docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)</sup>

You could use it like this:

```
from pathlib import Path


filename = Path("E:\\seaborn_plot\\x.dwt")
filename_replace_ext = filename.with_suffix(".txt")
filename.rename(filename_replace_ext)
```

Comment: even-though i name the way it does at unix, it behave the same while directory and user have permissions to replaced.